# Le neutre avec un nom féminin?

Tags: grammaire, sens, usage

> Vous êtes la maman de Michel ?
>   - oui, je la suis.
>
> Vous êtes pharmacienne/malade ? (Adj.)
>   - oui, je le suis.

Je ne suis pas troublée par les deux exemple ci-dessus mais avec :

> Vous êtes une bonne pharmacienne ?

est-ce :

> oui, je la suis.

ou  :

> je le suis.

?

Comment: 1/ I see one more time that you are using "être confondu(e) avec/par qqc." to render "to be confused about";  you can't do that. You can say "je ne m'embrouille pas dans qqc.", for instance. 2/ Your sentence is not clear and I couldn't make corrections (it is not grammatical either): "Je ne suis pas confondue avec les deux exemple au dessus mais là vous …". Try to explain what is **not** mixing you up and what is; it'll be a coherent question then. 3/ Even though the question is not well worded an answer is possible and I provided one, but it is better for all of us that you revised your text.

Comment: Ok. La prochaine fois, je vais faire attention.

Comment: I saw that you tried to do line breaks; in the source you must first type two spaces, then you can type the line break.

Answer (score 6):

In theory

> *Oui, je la suis.*

is a possible answer to:

> *Vous êtes la maman de Michel ?*

However, in real life, the answer will likely be:

> *Oui, c'est moi.*

*Je la suis* is too literary in this context, and mainly used to mean "I follow her" (*suivre*) nowadays.

Similarly, the second question:

> *Vous êtes une bonne pharmacienne ?*

might be answered by:

> *Oui, je le suis*.

but a much more common reply would be:

> *Oui, j'en suis une.*

Answer (score 1):

« La » est nécessaire dans le premier cas parce que dans « *la* maman de Michel » « la » est un article défini. Dans  le second « le » est nécessaire parce que dans « être pharmacienne » il n'y a pas de déterminant et parce que « malade » est un adjectif. Ceci est confirmé par *Le Bon Usage* dont voici les extraits applicables auxquels j'ai ajouté les caractères en gras.

> **1/**  Pour représenter soit un **adjectif**, soit un **nom construit sans
>   déterminant** ou avec un **autre déterminant que l'article défini,
>   le démonstratif et le possessif**, on emploie comme pronom
>   attribut « le  neutre », équivalant à « cela » (démonstratif)
>   - Ma sœur est une enfant, - et je ne LE suis plus (MUSSET, A quoi rêvent les j. filles,
>   1,3).
>   - Une femme compatissante et qui ose LE paraître (R ROLLAND, Précurseurs,
>   p. 24).
>    - fêtais mère et je ne LE suis plus (MAUROIS, Ariel, II, 4). —Je les appelle
>   assassins parce qu'ils LE sont (A. SUARÈS, Vues sur l'Europe, p. 169).
>    -  Servantes ? elles ne L'avaient donc jamais été (LA VARENDE, Troisième jour, p. 237).
>    - Des amis, nous LE fûmes bientôt en effet (AMBRIÈRE, Solitaire de la Cervara, p. 75).
>    - Nous sommes des meurtriers et nous avons choisi de L'être (CAMUS, Justes, p. 79),
>    - Nous n'avons pas à être des logiciens, même quand nous affectons de L'être (BENDA,
>   Précision, p. 73).
>    - Il y a des monstres ; nous ne LE sommes pas (HENRIOT, dans le
>   Monde, 11 déc. 1957).
>    - Oui, des dieux, et donc des fils de Dieu. Nous LE sommes
>   (MAURIAC, dans le Figaro litt., 26 sept. 1959).
>    - Beaucoup de crimes ont cessé de
>   L'être (FOUCAULT, Surveiller et punir, p. 22). — L'eau, plus glacée encore qu'elle ne
>   L'était pendant la nuit [...] (GENEVOIX, Rroû, p. 174). — Voir aussi § 246, a, 2°.

> **2/** Le pronom neutre « le » peut représenter un **adjectif de n'importe
>   quel genre et de n'importe quel nombre**, même d'un genre et d'un
>   nombre différant de ceux de l'antécédent
>   Les Mérovingiens ont été despotes autant qu'ils ont pu L'être (GAXOTTE,
>   Hist. des Français, 1.1, p. 185).
>    - Elle demeura tout interdite ;je L'étais beaucoup
>   moi-même [dit Adolphe] (B. CONSTANT, Ad., II).
>   - Elle était chrétienne. Son
>   père et sa mère L'avaient été (HENRIOT, Aricie Brun, III, 3).
>    - Mais si le père n'était pas exact à l'ouvrage, la fille L'était pour deux (R. BAZIN, Noellet, p. 19).

Comment: I would have expected *oui, c'est ça* (or some variant) in these examples. You've explained when e.g. *oui, je la suis* is grammatical, but could you comment on how natural it is?

Comment: @JD2000 Right away, I can refer only to a personal impression; neither "Oui, je le suis." or "Oui, je la suis." are pleasant to me and I just avoid them. I'd rather use a somewhat longer form: "Oui, je suis sa maman." or "Oui, je suis la maman de Michel." or even "Oui, c'est moi."  (which sounds quite correct also).